# Sprague-Grundy Value, deriving a Formula.

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

**Question**: Find a formula for the Sprague-Grundy value $(g(n))$ of a pile of coins of size $n$ with a subtraction set $\{1,4,5\}$.

I was able to find the periodic pattern for $g(n)$ as $0,1,0,1,2,3,2,3$. However my problem with these kind of questions is finding the formula for the pattern of $g(n)$.

So, for $g(n)=0$ the pattern is $n=0,2,8,10,16...$

for $g(n)=1$ the formula is for all $n$ such that $(n$ mod $2) = 1$

for $g(n)=2$ the pattern is $n=4,6,12,14,20,22...$ I can't derive a formula for this pattern

for $g(n)=3$ the pattern is $n=5,7,13,15,21...$

I would like to know if there is a method or an approach to derive these formulas to get the $g(n)$?

Thank you.

Comment: You asked for a method or approach to *derive* the formula, which makes it sound like you want to know how to prove the formula so you're certain it applies forever. But you accepted an answer that just shows you one particular way to *write* the formula. I guess you just meant "derive a nicer way of writing this pattern"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you found the periodic pattern, you can simply represent $g(n)$ as:

$$g(n) = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{for } n = 0,2 \pmod 8
\\1 &\text{for } n = 1,3 \pmod 8
\\2 &\text{for } n = 4,6 \pmod 8
\\3 &\text{for } n = 5,7 \pmod 8\end{cases}$$

or, if you are not comfortable with modulos:

$$g(n) = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{for } n = 8k &\text{ or }8k+2 &\text{for some } k \in \mathbb N
\\1 &\text{for } n = 8k+1 &\text{ or }8k+3 &\text{for some } k \in \mathbb N
\\2 &\text{for } n = 8k+4 &\text{ or }8k+6 &\text{for some } k \in \mathbb N
\\3 &\text{for } n = 8k+5 &\text{ or }8k+7 &\text{for some } k \in \mathbb N\end{cases}$$